# From EH action to Newtonian Mechanics action?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

How does one start from the [Einstein Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) go to the action of a (point particles + some field) in  special relativity and then Newtonian mechanics for a local neighborhood around a point for the FLRW metric?

$$G_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi \, T_{\mu\nu}$$

Can the below be done [explicitly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19796/2451) for flrw metric?

> One may also study the motion of non-freely-falling objects in general
> relativity and derive the equations for objects influenced by many
> forces although the formalism may look "advanced" in the language of
> general relativity and one recycles some concepts of classical
> physics, anyway.

Comment: EH action is only gravity. Where is the relativistic matter action? Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19796/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic can I see this: One may also study the motion of non-freely-falling objects in general relativity and derive the equations for objects influenced by many forces although the formalism may look "advanced" in the language of general relativity and one recycles some concepts of classical physics, anyway.

Comment: Done for flrw metric ? Also didn't see any links there in

Comment: Assuming $ds^2=\left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right)dt^2-dl^2$, have you calculated the expression for $R$?

Comment: @KP99 should I add a my attempt to the now closed question?

Comment: The question was closed soon after I added my comment above. Yes maybe you can edit and add a my attempt to this question

Comment: To reopen this post (v6), consider to focus question.